# Implement Globalization ư

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization

im curious about doing Globalization in asp.net MVC with globalization File and a Session["lang"]

the session lang can be setup quite easy to change, but the problem here is the Globalization File.

What should i do and how should i do to implement this?

Thank you very much

PS: I've search on Google and here for some solution but most likely with asp.net mvc we need to create another VIEW folder for EN, JP, FR, and this can cause a lot of trouble in the future to change the design.

---

Actually, it's mean translation: -> switching languages, something like that

Answer (score 0):

There's an article on l10n and i18n [over at codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Kb/aspnet/localizationByVivekTakur.aspx). For mere translation (= localization), it suggests either resource files (which is very common for .NET applications) or a database.

Your question doesn't make clear if you only want to translate your project or also want to globalize it?!

Comment: actually, it's translation, so that i can switch between language easily, also for the purpose of separate fixed text from template